# Is the superset and subset of a semi-decidable language also semi-decidable?

Tags: semi-decidability

Given three languages $L_1, L_2, L_3$ with $L_1$ and $L_3$ being semi-decidable and $L_1 \subseteq L_2, L_2 \subseteq L_3$. Can I deduce from these properties, that $L_2$ is also semi-decidable and how would I proof this?

Intuitionally it seems obvious that $L_2$ is also semi-decidable, but I didn't find a way to prove (or falsify) it.

So far I only found information about the closure of semi-decidability under $\cup$ and $\cap$. Can I use these properties in any way?

Comment: This question has been answered many times on this site.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Could you point me to them? As I couldn't find any fitting questions when I searched beforehand. Perhaps I used the wrong keywords (not a native speaker -,-).

Comment: There isn't an explicit answer to your question on this question, but, you can apply the same principal to your question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/are-supersets-of-non-regular-languages-also-non-regular/

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/17966/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22839/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22039/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12527/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/17860/755, and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/38486/755 where you will find answers to many similar questions -- those answers can be readily adjusted to this case as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because every language $L$ satisfies $$ \emptyset \subseteq L \subseteq \Sigma^* $$ and $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ are both semi-decidable.